# Any trick to override idex() function in Python so exception won't be raised if a string is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding, built-in

```
a = 'abc'
print(a.index('q'))
```

it obviously returns -1 but also an exception, so my question is simply how to remove the exception from the output and let -1 as the output only.

Comment: "it obviously returns -1 but also an exception," no, that doesn't make any sense. It doesn't *return anything*, it *raises an exception*.  Note, you can just use `a.find`

Comment: you can use use `-1 if a.find('q')==-1 else a.index('q')`

Comment: @sahasrara62 what? Why not jut `a.find('q')`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my bad operengineered solution,

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah I confused it the find method haha :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather say handle the exception instead of trying to override the built-in function like:

```
try:
    ind = string.index(substring)
    print (ind)
except:
    return f"{substring} does not exist in {string}"
```

But if you still want to override it here is one of the approach:

```
def index(string, substring):
    try:
        ind = string.index(substring)
        return ind
    except:
        return f"{substring} does not exist in {string}"
    
a = "abc"
print(index(a, 'c'))
```